# What is the meaning of "must match" in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, lucene.net

I have an requirement to modify the must match parameter in Solr.

```
 <str name="mm">
2&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;50%
 </str>
```

I'm not able to understand the logic behind this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm stands for Minimum should match parameter.
It helps you configure the number of the query terms that should match for the document to be returned in the search results.
You can configure it as a fixed number or as the Percentage of the Number of the Query terms that should match.

For detailed explanation and example check [link](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-The%7B%7Bmm%7D%7D%28MinimumShouldMatch%29Parameter)